# Sharepoint CSOM - how to filter out system/default document libraries?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I need to get all documents from Sharepoint site. I start with getting all the document libraries:

```
private IEnumerable<List> GetAllDocumentLibraries(ClientContext context)
{
    var lists = context.LoadQuery(context.Web.Lists.Where(list => list.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary));
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    return lists;
}
```

And then get all the items from each..

```
var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

_context.Load(items, i => i.Include(it => it.DisplayName, it => it.File));

_context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Problem is that there is a lot of system libraries that return files such as "controls", "edit-mode-21" and similar. I don't want to filter them out by specific names, since there could be other on another SP sites.

How can I know from the `List` and its properties if it is user-created list (meaning with documents that I need) or just a sys. library?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of conditions you can try. You need to check and select the combination that fits your case:

- `Hidden == false` - should exclude most of SharePoint internals (`Master Page Gallery`, `Solution Gallery` and others).
- `IsSiteAssetsLibrary == false` - this will exclude `Site Assets` and `Site Collection Images`. But can also exclude other image libraries created by users.
- `IsCatalog == false` - most of catalogs are also hidden, with exception of `Style Library`.
- `BaseTemplate == 101` - this is template for DocumentLibrary. This will exclude catalogs, image libraries, page libraries and probably some other.

Comment: Thanks, these 3 properties helped to eliminate nearly all "extra" files, I now have to deal just with some .aspx one. About BaseTemplate, wouldn't this exclude also user created doc. library that uses the default template?

Comment: BaseTemplate also can be 700 if you are using OneDrive/personal site.

Answer (score 2):

You can also exclude system-based lists and document libraries filtering with IsSystemList == false, as well as AllowDeletion == true.